# Add values stored in different Arraylist to a new one for the Arithmetic Mean

Tags: java, arraylist, sum, addition

I have multiple Arraylist and all have the same size :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1; // = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ]
ArrayList<Integer> list2; // = [ 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 ]
ArrayList<Integer> list3; // = [ 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 ]
```

The values are usefull only for the example.

sum them and obtain [9 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 9 ] then at the end [ 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 ] the average !

I want to obtain a new list called list4

```
list4 = list1+list2+list3
```

for the average, in this way I need also:

```
list4 = list4/3
```

How can I obtain this(whitout looping) ?

Comment: addAll , sumAll and then divide by 3. Looping seems unavoidable.

Comment: 1) `ArrayList` cannot be of primitive type; 2) loop is always necessary because resulting collection should contain multiple elements.

Comment: Adding of values in arrays is not possible without loops. have a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094664/3796048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an exact solution but the closer one would be in Java 8. You could do like `IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).mapToObj(i -> (list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i))/3).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Provided the size of all list is same. Example..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 })); 
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 })); 
        List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 })); 

        List<Integer> list4 = IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).mapToObj(i -> (list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i))/3).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list4); // Prints [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you tell OP that this code required JDK8.

Comment: That is the first line. I mentioned "In Java 8". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not at all possible without loops.

Even with streams in Java8 you can get the sum of individual `ArrayList` elements.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TheThom The answer is `not possible`

Comment: @SureshAtta Doesn't matter. It's still not an answer.

Comment: @TheThom Please down vote if you disagree with the answer.

Comment: @SureshAtta I don't disagree with it.